# How to properly use str.replace() with Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame like so

```
             Year        Player
46  Jan. 17, 1971  Chuck Howley
47  Jan. 11, 1970    Len Dawson
48  Jan. 12, 1969    Joe Namath
49  Jan. 14, 1968    Bart Starr
50  Jan. 15, 1967    Bart Starr
```

and I only want the year to populate `df_MVPs['Year']`. My current method is

```
df_MVPs['Year'] = df_MVPs['Year'].str.replace(df_MVPs['Year'][:7], '')
```

but this causes an error to occur. Is there a way to do this more simply?

**EDIT:**
I want my DataFrame to look like:

```
    Year        Player
46  1971  Chuck Howley
47  1970    Len Dawson
48  1969    Joe Namath
49  1968    Bart Starr
50  1967    Bart Starr
```

Answer (score 6):

Aw man, convert to a datetime then get the year:

```
df_MVPs['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(df_MVPs['Year'], format='%b. %d, %Y').dt.year
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take the last four characters of the string:

```
df_MVPs['Year'] = df_MVPs['Year'].str[-4:]

>>> df_MVPs
    Year        Player
46  1971  Chuck Howley
47  1970    Len Dawson
48  1969    Joe Namath
49  1968    Bart Starr
50  1967    Bart Starr
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `.str.extract()` method instead:

```
In [10]: df
Out[10]:
             Year        Player
46  Jan. 17, 1971  Chuck Howley
47  Jan. 11, 1970    Len Dawson
48  Jan. 12, 1969    Joe Namath
49  Jan. 14, 1968    Bart Starr
50  Jan. 15, 1967    Bart Starr

In [11]: df.Year.str.extract('.*(\d{4})$', expand=True)
Out[11]:
       0
46  1971
47  1970
48  1969
49  1968
50  1967
```

but you can also use `.str.replace()`:

```
In [13]: df.Year.str.replace('.*(\d{4})$', r'\1')
Out[13]:
46    1971
47    1970
48    1969
49    1968
50    1967
Name: Year, dtype: object
```

[Here is a link](https://regex101.com/r/mJ8dF3/1) which explains the `.*(\d{4})$` RegEx (Regular Expresiion)

Comment: can you point to where I can learn what "'.*(\d{4})$'," means? I am new to pandas/python

Comment: @Mark, i've added a link to `regex101.com` which parses and explains the RegEx expressions...